# Почему указатели в go считаются неизменяемыми?

Tags: golang, указатели

Только начал изучать Go.
Был уверен, что указатели изменяемые (Mutable).
Но в этой теме:
[Which types are mutable and immutable in the Google Go Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018081/which-types-are-mutable-and-immutable-in-the-google-go-language).
Ответу конечно больше 10 лет. Но всё равно. В одном из ответов сказано:

> Immutable Go objects: ... pointers ...

Я написал такой код:

```
var a, b int = 1, 2
var pt *int = &a    // указатель на переменную a
var ppt **int = &pt // указатель на указатель pt

fmt.Println("pt указывает на перменную a")
fmt.Println("Адрес указателя pt: ", ppt)
fmt.Println("pt указывает на адрес: ", *ppt)

pt = &b // теперь указатель pt указывает на переменную b
fmt.Println("Теперь pt указывает на перменную b")
fmt.Println("Адрес указателя pt: ", ppt)
fmt.Println("pt указывает на адрес: ", *ppt)
```

Вот такой результат можно получить:

```
pt указывает на перменную a
Адрес указателя pt:  0xc00000e028
pt указывает на адрес:  0xc000018030

Теперь pt указывает на перменную b
Адрес указателя pt:  0xc00000e028
pt указывает на адрес:  0xc000018038
```

После того, как мы поменяли адрес, на который указывает pt.
Сам pt остался тем же самым pt, на том же самом месте в памяти. Изменилось только его значение, точнее адрес, на который он указывает.
Так почему указатели считаются неизменяемыми (Immutable)?

Да, мы не можем гулять по памяти напрямую смещая указатель, как в C++. Как-нибудь вот так: pt=pt+1. Но конкретно в этом примере, ведь дело не в изменяемости, а в несовпадении типов mismatched types.

**Upd:**
Хорошо, передаётся по ссылке - мутабельный, по значению - немутабельный.
Я считаю, что путаницу вносит определение этих понятий.
Немутабельный - объект, который не может изменить своё состояние.
То есть в определении не сказано, что если мы например передаём в функцию адрес переменной, и внутри функции через указатель меняем значение переменной, то это не считается изменением состояния. И опять же в питоне вы не можете никак изменить состояние немутабельных переменных. А в Go не говоря уже о переприсвоении, даже указатели есть и для этого даже unsafe не нужен. Исключение составляют только строки. Вот для них и в спецификации прямым текстом сказано, что они не мутабельны.

```
a := "text"
a[0] = "z"
Результат компилятор ругается:
cannot assign to a[0] (strings are immutable)
```

Вот это я понимаю немутабельный. Для изменения текста строки нужно сделать массив из байтов, скопировать туда по байтам символы строки, и работать уже с новым массивом. То есть с другими ячейками памяти, в которых скопированы значения.

Comment: *"В одном из ответов сказано"* - не стоит слишком доверять ответам на SO, даже когда им более 10 лет, много голосов или высокая репутация у отвечающего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я перечитал несколько раз ответы по ссылке. Думаю, тут произошла классическая ситуация, когда простую штуку (передача по указателю и по значению) решили завернуть в модные концепции. Но немного не срастается (бывает). И начинают наворачивать философию. А оно все просто.

Вот со строками все просто, если у нас есть две переменные, которые указывают на одну строку и мы начинаем модифицировать одну с них, присвоив туда новую строку, то другая переменная все ещё будет указывать на изначальную строку. Это назвали умным словом "немутабельность". А по факту, мы понимаем, что у нас есть указатель на структуру в памяти, где собственно хранится сама строка. И когда мы модифицируем строки, то go компилятор вставляет код, который создает новые структуры. (Не забываем, что компилятор для go вначале написал человек, который  писал компилятор для си, поэтому, вряд ли он выдумывал новое).

Теперь посмотрим на обычный int. Тут ещё проще

```
a := 1
b := a
a = 2
//  тут b все ещё 1
```

вот этот же пример не вызывает вопросов? потому что мы знаем, что под капотом там просто копирование байтов. Но кому то пришло в голову назвать это иммутабельностью. Я думаю, что если бы b поменяло свой тип, то многие удивились бы, но если бы int при этом назвали мутабельным типом, то все бы сошлось.

То есть, если хочется понять все это, то нужно разбираться не от "мутабельный/немутабельный", а от сущности. что и куда копируется.

Теперь перейдем к мапам (они же словари, карты, map, dict).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    data := make(map[string]int)
    data["a"] = 1
    data["b"] = 2
    fmt.Println(data["a"]) // 1 - очевидно

    w := data
    data["a"] = 100
    fmt.Println(data["a"]) // 100 - то же очевидно
    fmt.Println(w["a"]) // 100 - а вот это и показывает сущность
}
```

последняя строка как раз и расскрывает сущность "мутабельного типа". Если бы мапы были немутабельные, то в последней строке вывело 1. Но по факту, там просто копирование указателей. И после этого все стает на свои места.

> но где же указатели? сейчас будут:)

Теперь пойдем к массивам, которые, как утверждается по ссылке на enSO, также мутабельный.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var x [5]int
    x[4] = 100
    fmt.Println(x[4]) // 100
    y := x
    x[4] = 200
    fmt.Println(x[4]) // 200
    fmt.Println(y[4]) // 100
}
```

а вот тут проблема. Если бы массивы были мутабельные, то в последней строке было бы 200, а там 100. А это просто ошибка в ответе. Массивы они немутабельные. Но Автор ответа это пропустил. Но как? а все просто. В go есть ещё slice (слайсы, срезы), которые очень похожи на массивы. Но они мутабельные. Проверяем. Меняем одну строку и смотрим

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := make([]int, 5)
    x[4] = 100
    fmt.Println(x[4]) // 100
    y := x
    x[4] = 200
    fmt.Println(x[4]) // 200
    fmt.Println(y[4]) // 200
}
```

Все сходится. То есть, у Автора вопроса тут ошибка. массивы - немутабельные, а срезы/слайсы - мутабельные. Но я бы сказал, что срезы это где то посерединке, достаточно посмотреть на append, который может возвратить как тот же указатель, так и новый - все зависит от третьего параметра в make. Если места достаточно, то append просто увеличит счетчик, допишет элемент и возвратит тот же указатель. Если места не хватает, то будет выделено новое место, скопированы данные туда, дописан элемент.

Я видел код, который работал из за этого нестабильно - срез передавали в функцию, которая могла туда добавить немного данных, и иногда выделенного места не хватало, происходило перевыделение памяти и срез вел себя как немутабельный тип (с точки зрения программиста).

Вывод. массивы - немутабельные, а вот для срезов я бы сказал, что эта концепция неприменима совсем.

А что же с указателями?

Как мы выяснили, у Автора ответа есть ошибки. Но я думаю, что тут все просто. Сам по себе указатель - это просто число, и он как и int немутабельный (потому что копируется). Но вот то, что находится по нему - уже зависит от содержимого. Собственно, если вчитаться, то автор на это и намекает. Если сделаете эксперимент, как я приводил выше, то убедитесь в этом.

Comment: Понято, как по мне мутабельный/не мутабльный работает хорошо в питоне. Во первых простая операция a = a + 1 требует выделения новой памяти. Потому что переменная int не может изменить состояние никак. И после инкремента это уже не та переменная, с которой мы работали изначально. В Go такая же операция просто перезапишет значение по изначальному адресу. В питоне нет указателей. А в Go они есть, и если аргумент у функции имеет тип *int, то наша немутабельная переменна int, поменяет своё состояние стоит только передать в эту функцию указатель на неё.